# How to save to Cassandra from java?

Tags: java, cassandra

I am new to Cassandra and i am working on a project that uses Cassandra as DB. The Cassandra is installed in another device and i will have to save it to the db remotely.

I have little knowledge about Cassandra and its functionality but I'm good with MySQL.

What are the steps to save a message into Cassandra?
Can I use the same database that I used with MySQL?

I believe that I will have to connect to the Cassandra Server and then save it.

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("localhost").withPort(3306).build();
```

I have used this statement to connect to Cassandra. (replacing localhost to the ip of the device)

Comment: Cassandra is different from mysql. The java driver docs can be found here: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a session with the cluster created  and the keyspace:

```
Session session = cluster.connect("keyspace");
```

create keyspace if u don't have one.

then use

```
session.execute(query);
```

to execute any query of your choice.

query has to be string and not null.

eg:

```
    String query= "INSERT INTO keyspace.table_name (id, lastname, firstname) VALUES (6ab09bec-e68e-48d9-a5f8-97e6fb4c9b47, 'KRUIKSWIJK','Steven');";
    session.execute(query);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet here is to start with the [java driver docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/). If you use maven its quite easy to setup, but I often find the examples don't always give a full `pom.xml` so you can use some of the [examples](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/3.x/driver-examples/pom.xml) in the github project

The [quick start guide](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/) gives a very simple example:

```
Cluster cluster = null;
try {
    cluster = Cluster.builder()   
            .addContactPoint("127.0.0.1")
            .build();
    Session session = cluster.connect();   
    ResultSet rs = session.execute("select release_version from system.local");
    Row row = rs.one();
    System.out.println(row.getString("release_version"));
} finally {
    if (cluster != null) cluster.close();
}
```

Some other items of interest are the [connection pooling](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/pooling/) and [load balancing](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/load_balancing/)

Comment: I have already tried this method. I am still not able to save any entity to the db.

Comment: The method above is a snippet from the docs to connect and jsut read a value. Perhaps you could update your original question with some more details on how you are trying to save since your example only shows a connection instance